# An Open-Source tool for Glassfish Performance Monitoring

Tags: performance, glassfish, monitoring

It seems the Glassfish Performance Monitor is commercial. When I wanted to download it from Oracle website it shown me a restriction.

Would you please suggest me an open-source monitoring tool for glassfish V3?

RGDS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly recommend Visual VM with the Glassfish plugin. Having purchased the GF Performance Monitor (which isn't open source or updated) I can say Visual VM does a better job. BTW, the GF plugin was written by the same folks who wrote the GF Performance Monitor.

https://visualvm.dev.java.net/

Comment: Both. You can get the source here.
https://visualvm.dev.java.net/source/browse/visualvm/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Glassfish very well, but do you look at somthing like [Sun GlassFish Enterprise Manager Performance Monitor](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7194/gifpw?a=view) in an Open Source version?

You can maybe found some interesting thing here:

- [New Monitoring Capabilities in GlassFish v3](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/editor/archive/2009/08/27/new-monitoring-capabilities-glassfish-v3)
- [Monitoring in GlassFish v3 Prelude](http://blogs.oracle.com/Prashanth/entry/monitoring_in_glassfish_v3_prelude)

Answer (score 1):

[JavaMelody](http://javamelody.googlecode.com) is another open-source monitoring tool for webapps.

Answer (score 1):

Lightfish http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/lightfish_an_opensource_glassfish_monitoring by Adam Bien.